# white space in mobile version (angular 6 mat-dialog)

Tags: android, css, angular, angular-material

So i got problem with angular material dialog.

[Mobile screenshot without chrome bar at top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYbEv.jpg)

[Mobile screenshot without chrome bar at top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qtzv.jpg)

But when i open dialog window appear some white line:

[Screenshot with dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uexDF.jpg)

So seems like it happens because chrome topbar is unseen. 
Is there any way to fix it?

UPD:1
Code of dialog:

```
this.dialog.open(HomeAboutUsComponent, {
  maxWidth: '300px',
  width: '90%',
  height: '80%',
  maxHeight: height + 'px',
  data: this.AboutUs[position]
})
```

CSS:

```
html{
   height: 100%;
}

body {
   margin:0;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Also got styles for scroll:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar
{
   width: 12px;
   background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
   background-color: #555;
}
```

UPD 2: 
Just added

```
html {
   background-color:black;
}
```

Line become black.

```
body {
   background-color:black;
}
```

Black too.

So seems like something wrong with content. Maybe app-root or anything else.

UPD 3:

```
app-root {
   background-color:black;
}
```

Line white.

```
app-root {
   height:100%; 
}
```

Not helping.

Comment: can you provide us your code so we can check ? Just by screenshots fixing this is really difficult

Comment: have you tried opening the dialog with 100% height?

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer, yep i tryed but it doesnt help. Seems like this white line is not html tag. I`ll add more details now.